# Flutter googleMap onTap longPress

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I'm doing a [tutorial to add a google map](https://medium.com/flutter/google-maps-and-flutter-cfb330f9a245) and my code is the following:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();



  static const LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433);

  MapType _currentMapType= MapType.normal;

  void _onMapTypeButtonPressed(){
    setState(() {
      _currentMapType = _currentMapType == MapType.normal
          ? MapType.satellite
          : MapType.normal;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Maps Sample App'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
          ),
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              GoogleMap(
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                  _controller.complete(controller);
                },
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: _center,
                  zoom: 11.0,
                ),
                mapType: _currentMapType,

              ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: _onMapTypeButtonPressed,
                  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.map, size: 36.0),
                ),
              )
            )
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After, the tutorial show how to add some Markers with a button but I want to improve this by add Markers when users do a long press on the map but I don't really enderstand how to implement this... I found some docs proves me the fonction exist but not really how to use it.
(found that I have to add onTap: [my method] in the GoogleMap() widget but this isn't recognize like a fonction)

Comment: Found my error, I was using an old version of the googlemaps plugin like in the tutorial...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First

```
Set<Marker> _markers = Set();
```

to add it to the map
Then add onTap:(your method it will get the LatLng be default) and Marker:(the _markers) to GoogleMap widget

```
                GoogleMap(
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                  _controller.complete(controller);
                },
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: _center,
                  zoom: 11.0,
                ),
                mapType: _currentMapType,
                onTap: (LatLng latLng) {
                  _markers.add(Marker(markerId: MarkerId('mark'), position: latLng));
                  setState(() {});
                } ,
                markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers),
              )
```

don't forgot to change markerId it must be unique.

Comment: It's says that 'onTap' isn't defined, I already tried like this but thanks for your answer.

Comment: you save my day and respect in office bro. Thank you